# Amazon Prodcut API Invalid Signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I want to use the **Amazon Product API** in my **Flutter** project.

I am testing my credentials via the [Scratchpad](https://webservices.amazon.de/paapi5/scratchpad/#%7B%22Keywords%22:%22853759005020%22,%22Resources%22:%5B%22Images.Primary.Medium%22,%22ItemInfo.ExternalIds%22,%22ItemInfo.Title%22,%22Offers.Listings.Price%22%5D,%22SearchIndex%22:%22All%22,%22PartnerTag%22:%22wishlists07-21%22,%22PartnerType%22:%22Associates%22,%22Marketplace%22:%22www.amazon.de%22,%22Operation%22:%22SearchItems%22%7D) but ALWAYS get:

> Error! InvalidSignature
> The request has not been correctly signed. If you are using an AWS SDK, requests are signed for you automatically; otherwise, go to https://webservices.amazon.de/paapi5/documentation/sending-request.html#signing.

I checked everything, reset my credentials, waited 24h, 48h, 2 weeks. But still, `invalid signature`...

I've contacted Amazon via chat, posted in the developers forum, but no answers.

What am I missing here? Why is it not working on the Scratchpad? Is it working for anyone? Is it maybe a Scratchpad-issue?

I want to test it first, before I actually do all the implementation.

Happy for EVERY help! Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: What happens if you try one of the code snippets at the bottom of the Scratchpad? For example, if you run the cURL snippet from your command line do you get the same error?

Comment: @andyb same, invalid signature

Comment: Can you confirm that: 1) You got your credentials by following [these instructions](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/register-for-pa-api.html) and 2) you get the same error if you select a different Marketplace (locale)?

Comment: @andyb yes. As for my understanding, locale does not matter since keys are the same across all marketplaces. But I already tried it with all marketplaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... how to waste 2 weeks.

So if anyone comes across this issue, make sure that you don't just copy the `secret key` by double clicking on the key and copy it via `cmd + c`, since this **WILL NOT COPY THE WHOLE STRING** in some cases (e.g. if there is a "/" in the String).

[image]